# Public CDN Anonymous Access

Tags: sharepoint-online, cdn

I have setup a public CDN in our SharePoint environment and the following cmdlet shows that it was successful

```
Set-SPOTenantCdnEnabled -CdnType Public
```

> Public CDN enabled locations:
>
> */MASTERPAGE
>
> */STYLE LIBRARY
>
> */CLIENTSIDEASSETS
>
> SITES/DEV/CDN

However when I try to access it anonymously, I get prompted with the O365 login. How can an external user access the Public CDN if it's behind a login wall. Am I misunderstanding how they should work?

Based on [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/office365/enterprise/content-delivery-networks?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fContent-delivery-networks-0140f704-6614-49bb-aa6c-89b75dcd7f1f) article, anyone should be able to access the assets within my CDN by just having the URL

Answer (score 1):

The article you link to says, "Requests for data in the Office 365 SharePoint CDN must be referred (redirected) from your Office 365 tenant or an authorization token will not be generated." It qualifies that other CDNs may have different standards, but it looks as if the expected default CDN behavior is exactly what you are experiencing.

Comment: That's so confusing because it also says "Content in public origins within the Office 365 CDN is accessible anonymously, and can be accessed by anyone who has URLs to hosted assets." Otherwise, why would it be called 'Public' ?

Comment: I speculate that "public origins" doesn't include SharePoint, but I agree that it is not written clearly.

Comment: There is a Azure CDN resource available, maybe that will do the trick for us